# Nutch Crawler doesn't retrieve news article content

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I was trying to crawl news articles from the links :-

[Article 1](http://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2016-07-05/apple-donate-life-america-bring-national-organ-donor-registration-to-iphone)

[Article 2](http://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2016-07-08/network-1-announces-settlement-of-patent-litigation-with-apple-inc)

But I'm not getting the text out of the page to the content field in index(elasticsearch).

Outcome of the crawling is :-

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.09492774,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "news",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "http://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2016-07-08/network-1-announces-settlement-of-patent-litigation-with-apple-inc",
        "_score": 0.09492774,
        "_source": {
          "tstamp": "2016-08-04T07:21:59.614Z",
          "segment": "20160804125156",
          "digest": "d583a81c0c4c7510f5c842ea3b557992",
          "host": "www.bloomberg.com",
          "boost": "1.0",
          "id": "http://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2016-07-08/network-1-announces-settlement-of-patent-litigation-with-apple-inc",
          "url": "http://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2016-07-08/network-1-announces-settlement-of-patent-litigation-with-apple-inc",
          "content": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "news",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "http://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2016-07-05/apple-donate-life-america-bring-national-organ-donor-registration-to-iphone",
        "_score": 0.009845509,
        "_source": {
          "tstamp": "2016-08-04T07:22:05.708Z",
          "segment": "20160804125156",
          "digest": "2a94a32ffffd0e03647928755e055e30",
          "host": "www.bloomberg.com",
          "boost": "1.0",
          "id": "http://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2016-07-05/apple-donate-life-america-bring-national-organ-donor-registration-to-iphone",
          "url": "http://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2016-07-05/apple-donate-life-america-bring-national-organ-donor-registration-to-iphone",
          "content": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

in which we can notice that content field is empty. I've tried with different options in nutch-site.txt. But still the outcome remains the same. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why nutch couldn't extract article contents. But I found a workaround for this using Jsoup. I have developed a custom parse-filter plugin which parses the whole doc and sets the parse text in ParseResult returned from parser filter. And used my custom-parse filter by replacing parse-html plugin in `parse-plugins.xml`

It will be something like :-

```
   document = Jsoup.parse(new String(content.getContent(),"UTF-8"),content.getUrl());
   parse = parseResult.get(content.getUrl());
   status = parse.getData().getStatus();
   title = document.title();
   parseData = new ParseData(status, title,parse.getData().getOutlinks(), parse.getData().getContentMeta(), parse.getData().getParseMeta());
   parseResult.put(content.getUrl(), new ParseText(document.body().text()), parseData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an out of context answer, but try using Apache ManifoldCF . It provides inbuilt connector to elastic search, and a better logged history to figure out why the data wasn't indexed .The connector section in ManifoldCF allows you to specify , that in which field your content should be indexed . It's a good open source alternative to try your hands on .

Comment: Thanks :) . I will have a look at it.

Comment: I would like to select links inside a particular div or any other tag and get the content of that links and index them. Whether we can do anything like this with manifold